# How does the archive manager check for content unchanged vs content changed?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am checking the following documentation and looking for little bit more information on How archive manager checks for content changes.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ArchiveManager_10SP2/concept_756FB4CA97E94AE9836229E605A06CAD

Scenario:

1. I have Component A with related Components field links to Component 
   B,C,D.
2. On my page A, we add the Component A with Template A and
   publish the page A.
3. On Publish Archive Manager is processing this
   and storing the a version in Archive Manager DB.
4. Subsequent updates to the content is done on any of Component B, C , D.

When we re-publish Page A, does Archive Manager process it as a new copy ? Right now, we see it for some updates and we do not see it for some updates.

We want to get some clarification on the below documented.

- Republication (content unchanged) — When the page is republished, the
  Archive Manager checks to see whether the content of the page and/or
  its artifacts has actually changed. If neither the contents of the
  page nor its artifacts have changed, a new version of the record is
  created to indicate the resource has been republished, but the
  content itself is not rearchived.
- Republication (content changed) — when the page is republished, and
  its content has changed, a new version of the record is created and a
  new entry for its content created.

How does Archive Manager checks whether its artifacts changed or not? Does it check Componet A, B, C , D and Page A ?

Any clarification will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive Manager's archiving happens in Tridion's content deployment phase and it doesn't reach back to the Content Manager.

The archiver determines which Component Presentations are being deployed by looking at the instructions that the Publisher put into the transport package. But as far as I remember (it's been a while) it only uses the actual web page to determine whether the Components have been changed.

Comment: Thank You Frank for the clarification.  Understood that the Archive Manager does not reach back to CMS, so it is unaware of the updates. In that scenario, if we update related components and publish the Archive Manager will not be creating a new version of the page which might not meet our requirement of version for every change, but you answered my question.